# Display images from private directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some images stored in a directory which is not accessible via the URL (the directory is not public).

How can I display those image in the html page using PHP?

Comment: Why the downvote? I can change the question if I missed something, just need to tell me...

Comment: Is the directory accessible with the `exec`command?

Comment: @pc-shooter if I need to rely on OS commands, I would prefer to redesign that part of my application. However I'm hoping that there is an easier solution.

Comment: I had a similar requirement. Don't know if this would solve your issue, but in my `.htaccess` for that directory, I had `deny from all` saved and did this for the PHP. [Code Link](http://pastebin.com/WnccvTRG)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally you'd just make that directory accessible, but if that's absolutely not possible then you can do this:

myimage.php

```
$file = 'privatedir/image.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit();
```

Then use myimage.php as the img tag src.

Comment: The OP probably needs to display more than one image. In this case, passing the filename as a query string argument to the PHP script would be nice (just be sure to sanitize it thoroughly first).

Comment: Will I lose in performance if I use this method to display images? Maybe I should think of caching the output of readfile.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, you will loose performance. But you have asked for it to do with PHP, so you loosing performance is within you requesting it to do with PHP.

Comment: You absolutely will loose performance, make the images accessible or move them to somewhere accessible if performance is a concern and you don't need to add additional access conditions (such as being a logged in user) to view the file.