# file path returning Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php

I am getting this error message

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I have a file `class_start_paperwork.php` file that is in the include folder creates pdfs and jpgs to the private folder

so

I am trying to show the image in the `user_group_start_paperwork_esign2.php` file which is in the public_html folder

```
"/root  
    /private
        /scratch
            /1387.2742.1487969899-0.jpg"


"/public_html
        /include
            /class_start_paperwork
        /user_group_start_paperwork_esign2.php"
```

it is creating the images

I just can’t load the jpgs

```
<img src= '../private/scratch/1387.2742.1487969899.0.jpg'  width=800 height=1100 />
```

is what is in the page source is

Comment: how are you trying to load the jpgs? and is the jpgs accessible by web server? `/root/....` doesn't seem to be a good place to give permission for web server

Comment: `../private/scratch/` translates to `/public_html/private/scratch` and most probably worthless in HTTP context as normally `/public_html` in hard disk   translates to `/`

Comment: $doc_1_jpg = "<img src= '../private/scratch/1387.2742.1487969899.0.jpg'  width=800 height=1100 />" ;

Comment: my script is in php and creates the jpgs from a pdf.  I am then loading it into a .tpl file

Comment: the private folder and the public_html are on the same level.  The jpg is in the private/scratch folder

Comment: web servers won't normally have access to `/root` and even if you give the permission **(huge security risk)** in your development machine you may not be able to host the script anywhere. Also `/public_html` is `/` for your web server and `../` from `/` will make no sense. try moving the jpgs to `/public_html/private/scratch/` and use `src='/private/......`

Comment: That will work but I am trying to keep the jpgs out of the public_html

Comment: `jpgs out of the public_html` won't work and btw why would you want it outside if anyhow you are going to serve it to public directly

Comment: I am creating a temp jpg.  having an individual sign it and then deleting the original jpg.  the signature is then saved with the data as well as a pdf of the signed jpg.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the /private folder is outside the public world zone. You would have to move the contents of /private folder into the public zone and relink for the web browser to be able to access.

If you would be displaying the images using server side language, that would be a possibility with the correct permissions.

This answer has some good info: [Display images from private directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321172/display-images-from-private-directory)

> Ideally you'd just make that directory accessible, but if that's absolutely not possible then you can do this:
>
> myimage.php
>
> $file = 'privatedir/image.jpg';
> $type = 'image/jpeg';
> header('Content-Type:'.$type);
> header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
> readfile($file);
> exit();
>
> Then use myimage.php as the img tag src.

Comment: When you say "make that directory accessible" what do you mean?

Comment: Option 1: Move the private folder into the public folder. That way it's accessible by the world. Option 2: You can also create another virtual site with a subdomain or different domain with all private photos which must be setup to be accessible by the world as well.

Comment: The images are peoples start work paperwork so personal data.  So don't want word to see.  The images are to be deleted immediately.  Currently the pdfs are loaded into an iframe.  I am re coding cause I need the jpgs.  The page creating the iframe is able to access the same folder

Comment: I'm layering 2 different divs and a canvas  in order to sign the jpg.  layer 1 is the document. layer 2 is the signaturePad canvas and 3 is a frame showing where to sign.

Comment: The my image.php route seems to be how it is being done now with the pdfs

Answer (score 0):

this worked perfectly

myimage.php

$file = 'privatedir/image.jpg'; $type = 'image/jpeg'; header('Content-Type:'.$type); header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); readfile($file); exit();

Then use myimage.php as the img tag src.